# Best way to test all combinations on inputs to a function in ruby

Tags: ruby, testing

I have found the I often repeat a similar pattern in my tests and was wondering if there's a tool that could help me DRY them up. If there isn't, I would like some feedback on whether you think this could be useful. Or maybe I'm not structuring my test properly?

Say you want to test a method on a class that takes several parameters and the method returns a boolean. For that sake of the example, the method is used to determine if a UI element should be displayed. So the definition would something like:

```
def should_display(controller_name, account, user)
  controller_name == 'Dashboard' && 
    account.has_feature(:secret_widget) && 
    user.can_access(:secret_feature)
end
```

Testing this simple method in the traditional way can be painful because you would need to test every possibility.

The a complete test would look something like:

```
setup do
  @my_object = MyObject.new
end

test "should display with controller name = 'DashBoard', account has feature, user can access secret feature" do
  assert @my_object.should_display 'DashBoard', make_account_with_secret_widget_feature(),  make_user_with_secret_feature_access())
end

test "should display with controller name != 'DashBoard', account has feature, user can access secret feature" do
  assert_false @my_object.should_display 'DashBoard2', make_account_with_secret_widget_feature(),  make_user_with_secret_feature_access())
end

test "should display with controller name != 'DashBoard', account does has feature, user can access secret feature" do
  assert_false @my_object.should_display 'DashBoard', make_account_without_secret_widget_feature(),  make_user_with_secret_feature_access())
end

test "... 2^3 tests total to cover every possibility" do 
end
```

What I would like to be able do to would to define the possible input and the expected output in a generic maner. Something like (pseudo code ahead):

```
controler_names = ['DashBoard', 'DashBoard2']
users = [make_user_with_secret_feature_access, make_user_without_secret_feature_access]
accounts = [make_account_with_secret_feature_access, make_account_without_secret_feature_access]

TestCombinations(controller_names, users, accounts) do
  execute do |args*|
    MyObject.new.should_display(*args) 
  end
  for_inputs('DashBoard', users[0], accounts[0]).expects(true)
  othewise.expects(false)
end
```

I know there are things like RubyFIT(http://fit.rubyforge.org/) that does something similar (i.e. testing business rules), but that requires an external text file which I'm not a big fan of. I would prefer to keep it to code.

If you know of anything that could help, I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Before you do this, read up on [Pairwise Testing](http://www.pairwise.org/):

> Pairwise (a.k.a. all-pairs) testing is an effective test case generation technique that is based on the observation that **most faults are caused by interactions of at most two factors**. Pairwise-generated test suites cover all combinations of two therefore are much smaller than exhaustive ones yet still very effective in finding defects.

Answer (score 2):

Well, not sure about your testing framework, but I've (ab?)used RSpec for similar things..so I'll use this here if you don't mind.
Adapting to your example:

```
describe MyObject do
  controller_names = ['Dashboard', 'Dashboard2']

  users =    [ User.new('Chuck', [:secret_feature, :normal_feature]), 
               User.new('Joe', :normal_feature)]

  accounts = [ Acc.new('VIP account', :secret_widget), 
               Acc.new('Normal account', :boring_widget)]

  allowed = [
             [controller_names[0], users[0], accounts[0]] #, etc, ..
            ]

  before :all do
    @my_object = MyObject.new
  end

  controller_names.product(users,accounts).each do |cn, u, a|
    expected_result = allowed.grep([cn, u, a]).size > 0
    it "should return #{expected_result} for controller:#{cn} user:#{u.name} account:#{a.name} combo" do
      result = @my_object.should_display(cn, a, u)
      result.should == expected_result
    end
  end
end
```

To run this, here's some fake business logic:

```
class MyObject;
  def should_display(controller_name, account, user)
    controller_name == 'Dashboard' && 
      account.has_feature(:secret_widget) && 
      user.can_access(:secret_feature)
  end
end
class Base < Struct.new(:name,:features); 
  def has?(feature)
    [*features].grep(feature).size > 0
  end
end
class Acc < Base; alias has_feature has? end

class User < Base; alias can_access has? end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have, in the past, just used arrays of valid and invalid values. I used it quite a bit, especially in security applications to make sure security didn't break in unexpected ways without me knowing about it.

The general, ad-hoc approach I eventually adopted was similar to what is shown below. It's still a fair amount of repetitive typing, but I suppose you could pass in the array with good and bad data, as well as a symbol to the action (or something similar) to generalize the approach.

A similar example here was used to test valid usernames, where the rules were:

- The username must be at least 5 characters
- It must start with a letter
- It must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores

Sample setup/test:

```
setup do
  @invalid_usernames = ["^%$#@", "123abc", "a", "", "    aaa", "otherwise valid username but it has spaces"]
  @valid_usernames = ["dude_", "frank", "dude123", "as_many_underscores_as_you_want"]
end

test "valid and invalid inputs work as expected" do
  @invalid_usernames.each do |iun|
     get some_action(iun)
     assert response.should_not be :success # or whatever the proper response is
  end

  @valid_usernames.each do |vun|
    get some_action(vun)
    assert response.should be :success
  end
end
```

This had the advantage that, when I ran into a case where an input that should have been valid, but wasn't (or vice versa) all I had to do is add it to the appropriate array, and run the test again, rather than writing a new test, or modifying the existing test.

Like I said, it might be possible to generalize this even further, perhaps writing a method that takes in hashes of valid and invalid input, along with the methods to run it against, but this is where I stopped in my particular case.

The **disadvantage** of this approach was that when a test failed, it wasn't always clear on which array element it failed, because it's just in a loop, and there's no output to show you which element was being asserted as valid/invalid. If you build your test cases carefully, and the list doesn't get too long, then this doesn't become a major problem, however.